Bluetooth and LED Problem with wifi+blutooth adapter (realtek8821cu)
I am using ubuntu 24.04 in dual boot with Win11 pro.My adapter is works fine in win 11 pro.In ubuntu my blutooth is not connecting to my headset and.But when i turn on wifi it connects to the headset.if i want to use bluetoth i have to turn on wifi single time.And the blinkg LED of adapter not working in ubuntu but it works fine in windows.Help me to solve the problems.
